# Login to remote application using PHP Curl and persist through browser

Tags: php, spring, curl, cookies

I am working on a script for login to a remote Spring Java application using PHP by passing the parameters using CURL. The login works fine, and I get the desired curl response, however I am unable to navigate through the application as a logged in user through my browser. How can I achieve it? This is my code.

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/j_spring_security_check',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 FirePHP/0.7.4',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields_items,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE =>'C:\www\mycookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'C:\www\mycookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,  

));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: does cookies get registered? check cookies in browser?

Comment: @Kool-Mind Cookies are getting created but the value of cookies fetched by PHP app is different from the one's registered by Spring application. I am talking about the JSESSIONID cookie in this case